# Some simple math isn't working in my helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a `grade` function:

```
def grade(submission)
score_counter = 0
total_score = submission.test.questions.size

#the scoring logic is here

return (score_counter/total_score)*100
end
```

The intention is to return a percent score, but all that shows up in my view is `0`. If I just try to return `score_counter` and `total_score` separately, they display the correct values. Any ideas?

Comment: according to your correct code, the o/p is always 0 since the score_counter is 0, you should add some code logic or something which will be useful to answer your question.

Comment: you are not updating score_counter anywhere?

Comment: I omitted the code I didn't think was necessary. The `score_counter` definitely works, and so does `total_score`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your values to float

```
(score_counter.to_f / total_score.to_f) * 100
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted it, can you please specify the reason for downvoting?

Comment: this worked :) was it because my stuff was in integer?

Comment: yes, by default ruby will return you result in integer if both the values are integer

Comment: yeah just did I don't know who downvoted you but i voted you up again.